# Show a strict global maximum for a multivariable function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, extreme-value-theorem

I have to show that $(1,1)$ a strict global maximum for $(x,y)\rightarrow xye^{-x-y}$ with $x > 0$ and $y > 0$.

First I calculated the derivatives: $$\frac{∂f}{∂x}=y(x-1)(-e^{-x-y})
$$$$\frac{∂f}{∂y}=x(y-1)(-e^{-x-y})$$

Therefore I know that $(1,1)$ and $(0,0)$ are the critical points. With the second derivative test I get that $$\frac{∂^2f}{∂y²}(1,1)\leq0$$  and therefore (1,1) is a local maximum. Now how do I show, that $(1,1)$ is also a global and a strict maximum in a two variable function?

Comment: What can you say about $xe^{-x}$ for $x\rightarrow \infty$ and why does this save the day?

Comment: $xe^{-x}$ converges towards 0 for $x \rightarrow \infty$ and has a global maximum at x = 1. But how do I prove that I can use this argument, because $xy \neq -(x+y)$?

Comment: $e^{-x-y}=e^{-x}\cdot e^{-y}$

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much!