# Show that the maximumof $f$ isglobal

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, global-optimization

I want to show that $f(x,y)=xye^{-x-y}$ has a global maximum in $(1,1)$.

So we have to show that $f(x,y)\leq f(1,1)$, or not?

We have that $$xye^{-x-y}=\frac{xy}{e^{x+y}}\leq xy$$ But how can we continue? I don't really have an idea. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: **These are only some hints.** You can first show that the critical points of $f$ are $(0,1)$, $(0,0)$,$(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$. So if $f$ has a global maximum it is among this points. Try to draw this graph, for example on geogebra. Clearly you should also in your post specify the domain of definition of your function, because it cannot be $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4172147/show-a-strict-global-maximum-for-a-multivariable-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your claim is not true if the domain includes $x<0,y<0$.

Hint:

For $x,y>0$ just write

$$xye^{-(x+y)}=\left(xe^{-x}\right)\left(ye^{-y}\right)$$

and note that $te^{-t}>0$ attains for $t>0$ its maximum $\frac 1e$ at $t=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! :-)

Comment: @MaryStar : You are welcome :-)